# Reduce margin when resizing window

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a part of my site responsive but I am running into a issue that I can't seem to solve.

I have 3 rectangular inline-block divs per "row" with margin-right:100px in a wrapper that are dynamically added. At the moment when I make my window smaller the third div does not fit on the row anymore and is pushed under as expected.

But what I want to achieve is that the margin-right get's smaller until let's say 20px in-between the div's and that then the third div is pushed to the second row and the margin get larger again until it does not fit again and then the second div moves to the second row and the third div to the third row and so on.

**Html:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box{
    width:100px;
    height:150px;
    background-color:red;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:96px;
}
.box:nth-child(3n+3) { 
    margin-right: 0px; 
}
#wrapper{
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

**Here is my fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/wucz4nhs/1/

Here are some images to make it more clear:

**Starts like this:**
[image: start]

**When resizing the space in-between get smaller**
[image: when resizing]

**When it doesn't fit anymore it goes to 2 divs per row**
[image: doesnt fit]

Comment: You can use media rules for that purpose or better a front-end framework like Bootstrap

Comment: like this: https://jsfiddle.net/wucz4nhs/2/ ?

Comment: @mwl Yeah something like that! thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should use `xy%` instead of `xy px`.

`margin: 5% 5% 5% 5%;` will use 5% of your website's width at the left and the right and 5% of your website's height. In that way it is responsive without using `@media screen and (max-width: xy px)`.

Comment: That could really use more explanation.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit in a hurry yesterday. :)

`margin: 5% 5% 5% 5%;` will use 5% of your website's width at the left and the right and 5% of your website's height. In that way it is responsive without using `@media screen and (max-width: xy px)`

Comment: Actually, top and bottom margins defined as a percentage will also refer to the containing block's *width*.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this with media queries. You can set these in your css for certain breakpoints.

For example:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .box {
        width: 50px;
    }
}
```

So when a browser or device is `768px` or less in width, `.box` will take on a width of `50px`. When doing that, however, you'll also need to add the `100px` width into a larger media query (else the media query will be overwritten). So when the browser or device is larger than `768px`, it will take on the `100px` width.

So you can remove the width property from the global `.box` do something like this:

```
@media (min-width: 769px) {
    .box {
        width: 100px;
    }
}
.box{
    display: block;
    height:150px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0 48px 0 48px;
}
```

Those are the simplest way to write media queries of course. There are tons of examples out there for specific width-sets and even device-specific.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: I don't want to change the width of .box but with the flex box from @birdmand and with your media queries ill probably get it to work. thank you

Comment: Oh sorry, I was only using the width as an example. You can add anything in there you'd like. Good luck!